# IE6 struts2 execute wrong action

Tags: internet-explorer-6, struts2

i'm facting a weired problem when executing my struts2 app using IE6.

I've got a 'submit' and 'cancel' button in my form:

<s:form namespace="/myns" action="submituser" >

. . .

< s:submit type="button" value="back"  label="Back" action="init"/>

<s:submit type="button" value="next"  label="Next" action="submituser"/>

....

When i click on "Next" the request gets forwarded to 'init'. But this only happens when using IE6 mozilla ie8 etc work fine.

any ideas?

thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

I think it is 'type="button' which is causing the issue.

See here for an explanation as to what IE 6 is up to: http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/ie6-and-multiple-button-submit-elements/